# jquery mobile add element with classes

Tags: jquery, class, mobile, element, addition

I add items to the list, but they are not connected classes. How to make the added clearance? I work with listview Thumbnails.

```
<div class="content-primary" >    
<ul data-role='listview' id="games_list"><li>
 <a href='index.html'>
 <img src='images/default.png'/>
 <h3>aaaaaaaaa</h3>
 <p>bbbbbbb</p>
 </a>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and script:

```
for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; ++i)
{
    games_list += "<li>\r\n\t<a href='index.html'>\r\n\t\t<img src='images/"+response.data[i].icon+"'/>\r\n\t\t<h3>"+response.data[i].name+"</h3>\r\n\t\t<p>"+response.data[i].description+"</p>\r\n\t</a>\r\n</li>\r\n";
}
$("#games_list").append(games_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question but your append must be inside of your loop

```
for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; ++i)
{
    games_list += "<li>\r\n\t<a href='index.html'>\r\n\t\t<img src='images/"+response.data[i].icon+"'/>\r\n\t\t<h3>"+response.data[i].name+"</h3>\r\n\t\t<p>"+response.data[i].description+"</p>\r\n\t</a>\r\n</li>\r\n";
$("#games_list").append(games_list); 
}
```

you can also use each instead of your loop,

Comment: games_list collect and append - adds all! response.data.length - amount line from sql query. += operation

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to attach classes to items you append? Just add it in to the appended code:

```
    myClass='foobar'
    games_list += "<li class='' + myClass + ''>\r\n\t<a href='index.html'>\r\n\t\t<img src='images/"+response.data[i].icon+"'/>\r\n\t\t<h3>"+response.data[i].name+"</h3>\r\n\t\t<p>"+response.data[i].description+"</p>\r\n\t</a>\r\n</li>\r\n";
```

I think that's what you're asking, but if not please clarify.

Comment: If nothing is found, it will do so.
There's not just a class, there is the sea of classes and different options.
For example, for li: class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li 

ui-li-has-thumb ui-btn-up-c"

Comment: You can handle that the same way as above, just with a longer variable. Just concatenate all of the classes into a single string variable and then pass that variable per my example. If you need to find out which classes go where, run them through a for loop with nested ifs and only return the ones that are valid.

Comment: That's all I know. I just think there is some sort of method or function that will draw, something like mobileinit.